# Determining speed (class) of USB on PC

Tags: windows-xp, usb, speed, hub

Is there a method for determining the speed of a USB port on a Windows XP PC, without using a USB protocol analyzer?

I'm looking for something simple, such as looking at the Device Manager.

I would like to hook up some USB equipment to a USB 2.0 port, rather than the slower USB 1.0 or 1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the "Device Manager\Universal Serial Bus controllers" the USB2 controllers often contain "USB2" in their name (or "Enhanced Host Controller").

Otherwise the quickest way is often to just plug in a USB 2.0 device, and if Windows tells you it could work faster in a USB 2.0 port, then you're plugging into a 1.1 port. :)

HTH